# Downloading of zip file from my web hosting

Tags: wordpress, https, hosting, cpanel

I have some zip files uploaded in my public_html folder and the following links are not working:

http://www.indragni.com/android/TimePickerSample.zip

https://www.indragni.com/android/TimePickerSample.zip

However when I use the following URL, then it works:

[indragni.com/android/TimePickerSample.zip](http://indragni.com/android/TimePickerSample.zip)

I have 400 videos on Youtube which use the first link type. It will be lot of hasstle to fix them all one by one. Is there any setting in wordpress or inside cpanel etc where I can make the files to be downloaded even after usig http or https in the front.

I have SSL enabled on my website.

Comment: you need to configure both  port 80 and 443 for www subdomain and point on correct directory,

Comment: can you post an answer with more detailed steps with cpanel and wordpress

Comment: edit your post and add the config file of your domain, either apache or nginx